# wpf 4.0 datagrid template column two-way binding problem

Tags: wpf, binding, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the datagrid from wpf 4.0. This has a TemplateColumn containing a checkbox. The IsChecked property of the checkbox is set via binding.

The problem is that even if I specify the binding mode explicitly to be TwoWay, it works only in one direction.

I have to mention that the same code works perfectly in .net 3.5 with the datagrid from the wpf toolkit.

Please take a look at the .xaml and .cs contents.

Thanks in advance,

Roland

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="IsSelectedColumnTemplate">
        <CheckBox
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="dataGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                Header="Preselected"
                x:Name="myIsSelectedColumn" 
                CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsSelectedColumnTemplate}"
                CanUserSort="True"
                SortMemberPath="Orientation"
                Width="Auto"
                />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and the related .cs content:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<DataObject> DataSource = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();
        DataSource.Add(new DataObject());    
        DataSource.Add(new DataObject());          
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = DataSource;
    }
}

public class DataObject : DependencyObject
{
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(DataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectedChanged));

    private static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this part is not reached
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your Checkbox IsChecked binding in the datatemplate:
`<CheckBox 
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            />`

Comment: This works Great, but this is not working as expected. When you type one letter it changes the object right away. What happens if you have a trigger which fires the validation handler. it means it fires 1000 times if you type 1000 symbols? This is not right.

Comment: This might be an acceptable solution, tracking the LostFocus event.
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />

Comment: @Dilshod what do you mean by it will fire 1000 times if one types 1000 symbols? we're talking about a checkbox, right?

Comment: @Sese In this case you are using CheckBox which is fine, but if you use TextBox and bind to property it fires PropertyChanged event per key press.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the deal, the way the data grid works, is that it creates a data view and displays it instead of the original data, therefore when you simply bind a property in the `CellTemplate` it doesn't get propagated from the view to the data.

What you need to do is use the `CellEditingTemplate` so that the data grid knows when you're editing, and can propagate it to the data when done (or it can undo it if you cancel).

Here's the modified XAML for you:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IsSelectedColumnTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IsSelectedColumnTemplateEditing">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="Preselected"
    x:Name="myIsSelectedColumn" 
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsSelectedColumnTemplate}"
    CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource IsSelectedColumnTemplateEditing}"
    CanUserSort="True"
    Width="Auto"
/>
...
```

Comment: I don't think this is true. It works perfectly for me without the CellEditingTemplate using Sese's answer. The CellEditingTemplate looks like it would overcomplicate things and make them more difficult for the user. Surely more than one click would be required to click the checkbox.