# Binding not triggering Action<>

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, action, hierarchical-data

I have some code like this
this is a custom datagrid which displays hierarchical data which should close and open.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <loc:Def1 x:Name="initdef1"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="_dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Display, Mode=OneWay}" 
                   SelectionMode="Extended" >
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Col1">
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="{Binding Path=Level, Converter={StaticResource ConvertToThickness}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[0]}" Margin="4" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Cells[1]}" />
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

with this is def1
this class has the actual logic for all the processing and loading and mapping the data to the grid.

```
public Def1()
    {
        _columns = new List<ColumnDef>();
        _source = new ObservableCollection<Def2>();

        Def2.RowExpanding += new Action<Def2>(RowDef_RowExpanding);
        Def2.RowCollapsing += new Action<Def2>(RowDef_RowCollapsing);
    }
    void RowDef_RowExpanding(Def2 row)
    {
        foreach (RowDef child in row.Children)
            child.IsVisible = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("Display");
    }
    void RowDef_RowCollapsing(Def2 row)
    {
        foreach (Def2 child in row.Children)
        {
            if (row.IsExpanded.HasValue && row.IsExpanded.Value)
                RowDef_RowCollapsing(child);
            child.IsVisible = false;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Display");
    }
```

and this in def2
this class has the logic on how should the rows behave.

```
public bool? IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set 
        {
            if (_isExpanded != value)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                if (_isExpanded.Value)
                {
                    if (RowDef.RowExpanding != null)
                        RowDef.RowExpanding(this);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (RowDef.RowCollapsing != null)
                        RowDef.RowCollapsing(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The thing is when the checkbox is checked or unchecked nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, there is no checkboxes in the code which you've posted.

Comment: Sorry somehow i missed the checkbox part of the code.its just below the usercontrol I'll post it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Did you put a debug pointer in the setter of `IsExpanded` and checked? Also did you find any binding errors printed in the `Output` window of visual studio?

Comment: There is defined the `Def1` class in the resources section, but it is never used. Also the `DataGrid` control is bound to some unknown `Display` property, which I suppose is a property of a view model. Maybe the `Def2` class somehow related to the `Display` property, but I can't see anything yet without more details.

Comment: The display property exists in the def1. I can post the whole code here but that'll be an awful lot of code. So what should i do?

Comment: Ok i have found for reason the IsExpanded property is not getting bound correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer from a similar post [wpf 4.0 datagrid template column two-way binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929627/wpf-4-0-datagrid-template-column-two-way-binding-problem)

So I changed the code to

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsExpanded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="{Binding Path=Level, Converter={StaticResource ConvertToThickness}}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" x:Name="checkbox1"/>
```

Now it works.
But can anybody explain why i needed to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ?
It's not always required.

Thanks

Comment: Because by default this property equals to `LostFocus`, and I feel that DataGrid cells have some problems with focus changing. So you should change it to `PropertyChanged` so that the binding updates immidiately.

Comment: does this property default differntly to PropertyChanged in silverlight because in silverlight this is working without setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged.

Comment: Actually there is no such value as `PropertyChanged` in Silverlight, only Explicit and LostFocus. But the DataGrid control there doesn't have that bugs which exist in the WPF DataGrid, like that bug in your question.